# Symfony 4 Limenius workshop

Tags: php, database, symfony

I'm pretty new to coding with php and a friend of mine recommended the Limenius  [sf4 workshop](http://symfony4.limenius.com:7080/doctrine). However, I'm stuck at the very beginning just to set the database up.

When typing `php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql` into my shell (working on Windows) I get this error messages:

```
Error thrown while running command "doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql". Message: "An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'db_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"

In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 113:

  An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'db_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)


In PDOConnection.php line 50:

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'db_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)


In PDOConnection.php line 46:

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'db_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I did look for answers online but they all seem to suggest I need to set up my .env file - which I *did* according to the tutorial in the first step. The webserver runs well, too. I just don't see where I go wrong exactly. Anyone else struggled with this part or may have an idea? Like I said, I'm pretty new to this.

As a test I've tried to create a new db using the command `php bin/console   doctrine:database:create` - same error messages.

Comment: if db_user exists, he cannot connect on local mysql server. Try to connect to your Mysql server with this user.

Comment: Please share your `.env` file, at least the line related to database connection string

Comment: The thing is: When I'm going to http://localhost/phpmyadmin the database is not even there (using XAMPP). Also, I have no idea where 'db_user' is coming from since my .env file required me to set this URL:

`DATABASE_URL="mysql://travolta:travolta@127.0.0.1:3306/travolta?charset=utf8mb4&serverVersion=5.7"`

Comment: What is user & the password you are using to login into phpMyAdmin ?

Comment: root / root. I did log in with that to check and it's what's in my XAMPP config file. I don't get where this 'db_user' is comming from, I don't have one in my user accounts and my .env file is set according to your instruction. Thanks for the patience.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, it did work out well once I've realised I need to type in my credentials **twice**.

This is my .env file (without the comments at top):

```
DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:root@127.0.0.1:3306/travolta"

###> symfony/framework-bundle ###
APP_ENV=dev
APP_SECRET=9c47bf77dd9e746ab12e8fb021e226e1
#TRUSTED_PROXIES=127.0.0.1,127.0.0.2
#TRUSTED_HOSTS=localhost,example.com
###< symfony/framework-bundle ###

###> doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
# Format described at http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/configuration.html#connecting-using-a-url
# For an SQLite database, use: "sqlite:///%kernel.project_dir%/var/data.db"
# Configure your db driver and server_version in config/packages/doctrine.yaml
DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:root@127.0.0.1:3306/travolta"
###< doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
```

I did not notice the 2nd last line. I'm so sorry for that! Nevertheless, thanks a lot for helping me out and providing great tipps. It helped me to understand things better.

Answer (score 0):

The database user name or password is incorrect. You can edit this data in the .env file.

Comment: My .env file actually *has* another name and pw:

`DATABASE_URL="mysql://travolta:travolta@127.0.0.1:3306/travolta?charset=utf8mb4&serverVersion=5.7"`

Comment: There is no problem in syntax. Are you sure the username and password are correct?

Comment: I've changed both to 'root', but still the error message says the same (with user " 'db_user'@'localhost' " - where is this coming from?

Comment: Can you this print command "php bin/console debug:config doctrine"

Comment: I did and answered in a new answer since my post was toolong for the comment section. Didn't work, but thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

Add this line into your `.env` file:

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://{username}:{password}@127.0.0.1:3306/{database_name}
```

where:

- {username} : the username you use to login into phpMyAdmin
- {password} : the password you use to login into phpMyAdmin
- {database_name} : the database name you would like to use with your Symfony application

## Update

According to your comment, if you have not created your database yet, and you feel comfortable with phpMyAdmin, create one:

[image: Create database in phpMyAdmin]

Then, give the user, sufficient privileges:

[image: Give database user sufficient privileges]

Comment: I did exactly this now but with the same results, using:

`DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:root@127.0.0.1:3306/travolta"`

User and PW are correct, checked it in twice now.

Comment: Wen going to http://localhost/phpmyadmin the database is not even there. I don't understand exactly in which step this is going to be set up. I feel like I'm missing soething obvious, but this is all pretty new to me.

Comment: @DanielJ. Please check the **Update**

Comment: Hey, I did create the database and I gave myself all the privileges. But the error message is still the same :(

Comment: Check my new answer, worked out after all. So sorry for this, but I really appreciate your help!

Comment: It was and I will as soon as I can (not enough rep yet).

Comment: I had to use single quotes in my `.env` file: `DATABASE_URL='mysql://user:$AAA-555-BCDBCDBCD123123123==$ABCABC123123==@localhost:3306/new_db'`. Double quotes and no quotes resulted in `Access denied`. I also had to use `localhost` in lieu of `127.0.0.1` to avoid `Connection refused`.